# PHP - Why is this class declaration giving me errors?

Tags: php, class

> Parse error: syntax unexpected T_STRING on line 3.

```
<?php
class AttachmentEmail {
    private $from = 'noreply@site.com';
    private $from_name = 'Site';
    private $reply_to = 'noreply@site.com';
    private $to = '';
    private $subject = '';
    private $message = '';
    private $attachment = '';
    private $attachment_filename = '';
}
?>
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error-- it seems to be working for me.

Comment: I see no such error: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ILiA4A#

Comment: Are you using PHP 4 by any chance?  That's valid PHP5 syntax, but not 4.

Comment: Wow, I thought it updated successfully to 5, arg.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must be using PHP4. I just tried it in PHP 5.2 and it works just fine.

PHP 4 has a different set of rules for how a class is created versus version 5.

Run `phpinfo();` to get your version. If it is version 4 you might want to consider upgrading.

Comment: The crucial point here is that PHP4 has no `private` keyword.